# Why is Laravel trashed() method not found>

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

I'm trying to use the soft delete functionality of Elequent ORM in Laravel 4.1

Deleting records works as expected, however when I search for results using withTrashed() and then check to see if it was a soft deleted record using trashed() I get the following error

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::trashed()

Here is my code.  Any suggestions?

```
$product = Product::withTrashed()->where('url', Input::get("product_url.$key"))->where('prolist_id', $list->id)->get();

if($product->trashed())
{
    $product->restore();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`get()` is returning a collection of objects. If you only want one result, you can do `first()` instead and call `trashed()` on that. If you want several, you'll have to call the method individually for each item in a loop.

Comment: That makes sense.  Think I gotta brush up on the return values of the different methods...  Thanks for the reply!